# spark dataframe to bytearray

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to convert a complete spark dataframe to byte array.I used the below to convert a column to byte array but I want to convert an entire dataframe.

```
(x:String)=>encrypt(connStr(ECCConstants.S_Key).toString,x,algorithm)


  def encrypt(key: String, value: String, algo : String): String = {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider())
    val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algo) ///ECB/PKCS5Padding
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyToSpec(key,algo))
    Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8")))
```

Comment: What's the goal? What did you try?

Comment: @GaëlJ I am want to encrypt the entire dataframe with AES 256 ecryption like the way we do in Java and write to a file. I have earliar used the code to encrypt a single column but now I want the entire dataframe encrypted. I have updated the code details for better information spark.udf.register("AESEncrypt",(x:String)=>encrypt(connStr(ECCConstants.S_Key).toString,x,algorithm)